# Google cPanel and Zend/PHP

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-gdata

Im trying to retrieve all users from a domain, but I get an error..

Have downloaded the Zend library

Docs:

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/provisioning/?hl=da#retrieving_user_accounts

Get this error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method Zend_Gdata_HttpClient::retrieveAllUsers()
```

script:

```
require_once 'Zend/Loader.php';
Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin');
Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata_Gapps');

$email = 'alias@mail.com';
$password = 'password';
$client = Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin::getHttpClient($email, $password, Zend_Gdata_Gapps::AUTH_SERVICE_NAME);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($client->retrieveAllUsers());
echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: The cpanel tag is not to be used for "Google cPanel", just for future reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you try to access the retrieveAllUsers method on an instance of the wrong object (Zend_Gdata_HttpClient instead of Zend_Gdata_Gapps).

Try this:

```
$client = Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin::getHttpClient($email, $password, Zend_Gdata_Gapps::AUTH_SERVICE_NAME);
$gdata = new Zend_Gdata_Gapps($client, 'mydomain.com');
$users = $gdata->retrieveAllUsers();
```

Comment: ok thanks.. but that was not was the documentation told me.. Now I get this error `You must agree to the Google Apps Terms of Service before using this API` Where do you agree the terms?

Comment: Log in at google apps with the credentials for the user that is used in your php code above. I think you should see the terms here as soon as you log in.